# Upgrade Ionic 2.0.0-beta.32 to latest 2.0.1 or final release

Tags: ionic2, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Ionic environment to the latest version.

I have an existing app I built on Ionic `2.0.0-beta.32`. I want to upgrade it to the latest version `2.0.1` (or the `final release`).

My questions are :

1) How can I upgrade my environment ?

2) Is there any changes I have to do in my code ? (if yes please can you tell me exactly how to proceed it... ?)

Answer (score 1):

answering question 1:
try these in the root of your project

> sudo npm install -g ionic
>
> ionic lib update

question number 2 is hard to answer. generally you should be good. You should try running your code and do some regression testing and then ask specific questions if you face any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic provides upgrade instructions in their [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Usually it is enough to upgrade your package version, but sometimes when there are breaking changes that you need to manually address they will be listed on that page.

Comment: but there are many versions between `2.0.0-beta.32` and `2.0.1`, so it's hard to read all the changelogs and make code changes for each version.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no other way if you want to make sure that nothing breaks in your app.